# java - DataSource for standalone application - no application server

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling

I want to connect to a MySQL database from a standalone application. There is no application/web server.

This [page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) suggests that I should use DriverManager to create the connection. However [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/package-summary.html) page suggests that connections created from DriverManager cannot be pooled.

However connection pooling is a must for me because the application uses various threads to write to the database concurrently, so closing/recreating connections is not optimal.

1. Which DataSource implementation should I use for this purpose?
   I looked at [MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource](http://org.ntnu.no/musikkensverden/doc/com/mysql/jdbc/jdbc2/optional/MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource.html) but I am not sure if it actually implements a connection pool. I also looked at the Tomcat [DataSource](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/DataSource.html) which I am sure implements a connection pool but I am not sure if it can be used outside Tomcat.
2. When I close the standalone application what should I do to release the connections/pool properly?

EDIT: It looks like the Tomcat DataSource is [usable](http://people.apache.org/~fhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) from standalone application, so I am going to use it. It also has a close method which I assume will release the connections.

Comment: Look into C3P0 or BoneCP for 3rd party connection pools, regardless of the database you are using.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. i will keep these in mind for future

Comment: A `ConnectionPoolDataSource` is not a connection pool, it can be **used** by a 'normal' `DataSource` that provides pooling.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would advise to use a library like [DBPool](http://www.snaq.net/java/DBPool/). It'll take a lot of headaches away from you because the developer already took care of them.
2. To ensure proper cleanup of your connection pool, read the [documentation](http://www.snaq.net/java/DBPool/#Adv_ShutdownHook) about a JVM Shutdown hook.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i will keep these in mind for future

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apache DBCP and DBUtils

**[DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/)** will give you features for connection pool etc.

**[DBUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/)** will make jdbc easier for you.

As mentioned [DBPool](http://www.snaq.net/java/DBPool/) is also one, there is [BoneCP](http://jolbox.com/) and plenty pooling tools out there.

Take a look at some samples:

- [Connection Pooling using Apache common DBCP And DBUtils](http://javahunter.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/connection-pooling-using-apache-common-dbcp-and/)
- [Using Apache Commons DBUtils and DBCP](http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=45).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Apache Cayenne](http://cayenne.apache.org/), in doc read about [DataSource](http://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.0/dbcpdatasourcefactory.html) and [faq about connection pools](https://cwiki.apache.org/removed/CAY/connection-pools.html)

EDIT:

As a bonus you get modeler (graphical tool for database) and easy integration with Eclipse.