# Using connection pool in java

Tags: java, jdbc, jndi, pool

In my project I face a problem of inactive session on database due to lots of load. when I check v$session table I got 12000 inactive session so I thinking use connection pool for solve this issue so is it possible to use connection pool in java project not in web project ?

Because while use connection pool need to setup in context.xml and my project is not web project it is java application project

Comment: You can use a connection pool in a normal java application. Check commons-dbcp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java - DataSource for standalone application - no application server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15588449/java-datasource-for-standalone-application-no-application-server)

Comment: You can configure a connection pool in code. `context.xml` is just a possible method for defining that. It is not the only way.

Comment: Anybody able to provide me example because I am new in this and I searched also I didn't get any example